# Any way to include the App Registration name in the access token when using Client Credentials flow?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, clientcredential, azure-app-registration

I use Azure AD to implement auth^2.

When I use a access token from a user I get a claim such as unique_name or upn which contains a user identifier I can use to log into the DB for logging/tracking/auditing.

If I use an App Registration as a service principal with the Client Credential flow, however, the access token does not contain any claim with the App Registration name. The closes thing is the azp which contain the UUID of the App Registration. It is, however, a bit hard to read and it would be nice to somehow get the name of the App Registration in the claims for logging/tracking/auditing purposes.

Are there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I generated **access token** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

> However, the access token does not contain any claim with the App Registration name.

**Note** that: By default, the access token will contain App Name and App ID.

When I decoded the access token, **the App Name and App ID** is present like below:

[image]

**Hence** there is no need to create custom claims for App Name and App ID.

> It is not possible to add custom claims while using client credential flow.

I created a custom claim like below:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/appname","JwtClaimType":"appname"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "appname" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"


Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id d53b9689-3c0d-4c39-ae6d-efd733e10776 -RefObjectId fd49e655-b790-4368-b9d9-1cf09fda1ba2

Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id d53b9689-3c0d-4c39-ae6d-efd733e10776
```

[image]

I assigned the value to the claim like below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "testclaim"
    }
}
```

[image]

Now when I generated access token using **Authorization Code Flow** I got the claim successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. If I use the graph-api scope, I can get the same result as you - namely that both app_name and appid is included in the token.

However, if I use a another scope, i.e. a scope from the backend app registration (api://<backend-app-uuid>/.default), it is not included. Do I need to add some delegated scope from the Graph API to make it be included?

Comment: Yeah for that you have use delegated scope and delegated flow too.

Comment: OKay - just for my understanding: Why? Doesn't it more or less correspond to including the name of the user, if the token was aquired in a user-context? The service-principal is not, as such, getting the token on behalf of anything - just itself.